# Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalAdaptivePaymentsSDK, Version=2.12.117.0

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I keep getting the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalAdaptivePaymentsSDK,
>   Version=2.12.117.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of
>   its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference

and

> Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalInvoiceSDK, Version=2.7.117.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference

but I don't have any reference to those versions. I am using versions 2.13.117.0 and 2.8.117.0.

I am quite sure I don't have any dependencies that use them also. 
I have deleted all bin folders, and rebuilt but still get this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually this is because some other library has these as a dependency. Are there any other projects in this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a dll that has dependency with `'PayPalAdaptivePaymentsSDK, Version=2.12.117.0.`So please check all references and sure that all assembles has correct version

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys
My problem was, I replaced an old dll with a new one, but for some reason the copy was failing, after deleting and copying again, the problem went away. so yes I did have a dll with a ref to the old version.